# Baking displacement map with Cycles Experimental

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, displacement

I want to bake some displacement maps for Unity Engine. I want to use Cycles renderer. I have read that it's only available in Experimental version of Cycles, but when I changed Cycles to Experimental version there isn't baking type for Displacement map, there are UV, Normals, Shadows etc. but there isn't any Displacement/Depth map choice. I have Blender 2.78a (2016-10-24) downloaded yesterday. Where can I find this option or how can I enable it?

Comment: And what's wrong with Blender Render Displacement baking if I may ask?

Comment: I don't know how to pick output texture for baking result. In Blender Cycles we must create Image Texture witch choosen out texture, but in Blender Render? When I bake in BR, the result is given instead diffuse texture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Baking Displacement maps is very easy in Blender Internal. Switch to it.Then unwrap low poly object. Switch baking pass to Displacement, set appropriate distance.Enable Selected to Active. Select low poly object, switch to Edit mode.In UV/Image editor create new image (switch 32bit float on when generating), make sure, that UV map of the object is displayed on this new image.Tab out of edit mode, select first high poly object, then low poly object and hit Bake. Like this:[image]

Answer (score 4):

You were probably reading about Cycles displacement (like for the rendering not baking displacement maps). AFAIK Cycles doesn't and won't soon have this as a bake option. The workaround for now is to bake it out using the BI engine.

Answer (score -6):

BI has a huge disadventage comparing to cycles baking. It lacks cage baking! So if you're baking a bump map from highpoly model onto lowpoly and the curvature of the highpoly goes continuosly around it's corners (like a 90 deg or so) you'll get strange artifacts on those corners. There are some workarounds by adding certain modifiers to LP model while baking, but it's a kind of fiddling around to get the correct result.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: You do not want cage baking for displacement, unless you have a way to bake, store and use in the cage's projection vectors as well. You actually want to project right along the surface normal, because that's the direction your displacement modifier/shader will move the tesselated vertices later.