# create heightmap out of a plane and save it as an image

Tags: export, image, height-map

guys and girls - I found Blender editing mesh tools the best for my terrain needs, I mean I just need the mesh itself for a lowsized terrain (no more then 70 by 70 quads), without any of those normal terrain editors complicated things. And I have a question - are there tools or ways, or even tricks, to render this small terrain as a top view black-and-white heightmap and save it as an image, BMP preferable but no matter? The goal is just to have heightmap image in a file for further processing. Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67600/37728

Comment: thanks for immidiate response - my blender knowledge is not quite deep to get into the techniques the author suggests there, Ill try to play with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDqYx0GLcvw idea tomorrow, starts at 3:06, this one looks more clear for me, will leave all the conclusions by any results :)

Comment: well, for those ones instrested in another working solution this youtube tutorial does the job: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDqYx0GLcvw, just after having the mesh rendered orthographically you need to save the image (bottom-left menu at rendered screen).